# iOS / Swift | Infinite matrice of views : ScrollView or CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, matrix, scrollview, collectionview

I'm creating a infinite "matrix" of views. When I load my MainView, i create views around it. Then, if I scroll to the right view for example, I create new views around the right view.

> I tried to schematize what I want to do :

[image]

I'm asking 2 questions :

**1-** Should I use **ScrollView** and add views in it OR a **CollectionView** and add collectionViewCells (with size of MainView) in it ? Which one is better and Why ? I was going to use ScrollView and views but CollectionView allows reusable cells which could be very powerful with infinite matrix ...

**2-** Since User can scroll Top and Left, How do you manage to add views / collectionViewCells at "index -1" **without reloading or moving everything** ?

Comment: You are writing other view , main view, is this a UIViewController or an UIView ?

Comment: MainView is a UIView in a ScrollView or CollectionView, dunno for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. Create your own `UIView` subclass which has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. When the pan is recognized, update the position of your child views. Add & remove children around the edges, so that you never have too many children. (As views move offscreen, you can `removeFromSuperview`).

Comment: I need to keep all views, even if User moves away, he can come back and display it again, this is why I was thinking about UICollectionView and reuse cells

Comment: @Aximem Having all the views in memory will probably kill your app or atleast make the user interface very heavy loaded if you have a massive UI. That is not a good practice for that massive design you used. I would go with this solution as a guideline.

Comment: Ok I see, I really was thinking UICollectionView could help me with this memory issue but as you said I might display manyyyyy views and it might kill app or slow user interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Graham is right, and following the MVC model, You should not care about hidden / distant views: when you are about to show them (as tableview does..) You (or the controller..)  ask to your model the data to be displayed using a correct "key"

A bright sample are MapKit maps: the use tile, you can use a similar approach.